# Toggle property in an object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object and need to toggle the property based on the key. If the key is already true, sending in the same key should make it false. If a new key is sent, all the previous keys in the object should be set to false and the new key should be set to true.

This is my  implementation.

```js
// New key with value true
const obj1 = {};

const obj2 = {
  'A1': true
}

const obj3 = {
  'A1': true
}

const updateObj = (obj, code) => {
  if (code) obj[code] = !obj[code]
}

updateObj(obj1, 'A1');

updateObj(obj2, 'A1');

updateObj(obj3, 'A2')

console.log('obj1', obj1)
console.log('obj2', obj2)
console.log('obj3', obj3)
```

In the third example, it should return `{'A1': false, 'A2': true}`.

Please advice.

Comment: "In the third example, it should return `{'A1': false, 'A2': true}`." Why should it? Your example doesn't toggle `obj3.A1`.

Comment: But your are toggling only `obj3.A2` in your example. Why do you think that `obj3.A1` will toggle?

Comment: I want to toggle A1 in this case. And set A2 to false. How do i enhance this?

Comment: So you want all the properties to toggle themself and set `obj[code]` to false?

Comment: Yes, except for the passed in value which will be a new property with true

Comment: `const updateObj = (obj, code) => { Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = !obj[k]); if(code) obj[code] = true }`

Comment: @Nina Can you give me your view on this please?

Answer (score 0):

As the @Amir Popovich says, this is the best way to go

```js
    // New key with value true
    const obj1 = {};

    const obj2 = {
      'A1': true
    }

    const obj3 = {
      'A1': true
    }

    const updateObj = (obj, code) => { 
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = !obj[k]); 
        if(code) obj[code] = true 
    }
    updateObj(obj1, 'A1');

    updateObj(obj2, 'A1');

    updateObj(obj3, 'A2')
    
    console.log('obj1', obj1)
    console.log('obj2', obj2)
    console.log('obj3', obj3)
```

Comment: @amir I want obj2.a1 to get toggled. Since obj2.a1 is already true, sending in a1 again should make it false

Comment: If you want to be able to do that, you will always have to work with the same object or an array of objects. Because by passing each time a new variable to your function, we lose the history of your actions.

Comment: But why? I am working on new data and expecting the corresponding output

Comment: Your object is different for each function call, you pass obj1 then obj2 then obj3 ... Following this, no reference variable keeps the history.

Comment: Yeah, so they are different outputs I need to incur using the same function. The same function should give me the expected output based on the corresponding data I am sending in

Comment: Yes, you are right, you must convey different values, but you will need a benchmark. when you pass obj2, it is necessary for your method to remember that you passed it obl1 (because you passed it 'A1').

Comment: Yeah so I put that value in obj2 as some value.. I dont care about the previous state here. All I need is to toggle the values based on the current inputs given.